# Get trigger element from react-semantic-ui popup in jest and enzyme

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to write some tests but I have not found how to get the trigger-element from react-semantic-ui's Popup. Does anyone know?

This is the Popup; I want to test the Icon

```
<Popup trigger={<Icon name='plus' color='green' onClick={this.followItem.bind(this)} />} 
  content='Follow this item' />
```

current test method:

```
describe('Follow Icon', () => {
    it('should create a userItem when the follow icon is clicked', (done) => {
        const wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter><ItemDetails match={{ params: { id: 1 } }} /></MemoryRouter>);
        const instance = wrapper.find(ItemDetails).instance();
        instance.getItem().then(() => {
            wrapper.update();
        }).then(() => {
            expect(wrapper.find(Popup)).toHaveLength(1);
            const follow = shallow(wrapper.find(Popup).prop('trigger')());
            // wrapper.find(...).prop(...) is not a function
            expect(follow.props().name).toBe('plus');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works, but I don't know if this is best practice.

```
<Popup trigger={<Icon id='follow'/>

const follow = wrapper.find(Popup).find('#follow').first();
```

For some reason it does find 2 elements in '#follow', so the .first() is required;

If anyone finds a better solution, don't hesitate to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to call the function and shallow render the result. Let's say you have the shallow rendered the Popup, just call the `trigger` function and pass the result to `shallow`:

```
const icon = shallow(popup.prop('trigger')())
```

Comment: I get popup.prop(...) is not a function

Comment: how do you generate `popup`

Comment: `mount(<MemoryRouter><ItemDetails match={{ params: { id: 1 } }} /></MemoryRouter>).find(Popup)`

Comment: And does it find the popup, cause it doesn't look like it is.

Comment: When I test `expect(wrapper.find(Popup)).toHaveLength(1);` it works

Comment: I included the current test method in the question

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar problem and my solution for testing the Popup component (using your example) was:

```
<Popup 
  trigger={<Icon 
               name='plus'
               color='green'
               onClick={this.followItem.bind(this)} />} 
  content={<div className="content">Follow this item</div>}
/>
```

```
// after setting the wrapper
// to test the trigger property, as this is always rendered we just need to:
expect(wrapper.find(Icon).prop().name).toBe('plus');

// to test the component property, as this gets rendered in the document.body, 
// there is no way to assert on it using just one mount

const popupContentWrapper = mount(wrapper.find(Popup).instance().props.content);
expect(popupContentWrapper.find('.content').hostNodes()).toBeDefined()

// not sure if you notice the use of hostNodes here, but that's because find is
// returning both React components instances and DOM nodes, that match your query selector. hostNodes() solves the issue, reference: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/836#issuecomment-401260477
```